# Radio Button Validation not working on IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I have following code which validate the questionnaire form and post answers on the next page if all the required answers are entered by the user. This code works perfectly on the Chrome and Other browsers except IE(internet explore). It shows the alert message "Answer All Question" even selecting options all question. This thing is happening only in IE.. Can someone tell me why its behaving like this?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

//---------------Method for validating the Question whole form --------------//
function checkRadio(name)
{
  var radio = document.forms.myForm[name];
  for (var option in radio)
  {
    if(radio[option].checked)
    { return true; }
  }
  return false;
}

function ValidateQuestions()
{
  if (checkRadio("question1") && checkRadio("question2") && checkRadio("question3") && checkRadio("question4") && checkRadio("question5") && checkRadio("question6") && checkRadio("question7") && checkRadio("question8") && checkRadio("question9") && checkRadio("question10") && checkRadio("question11") && checkRadio("question12") && checkRadio("question13") && checkRadio("question14") && checkRadio("question15") && checkRadio("question16") && checkRadio("question17") && checkRadio("question18") && checkRadio("question19") && checkRadio("question20") ) 
  { return true; }
  else{ return false; }
}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------//

jQuery(document).ready(function($) 
{    
    jQuery('#submitFormC').click(function()
    {
     var str = $("#questionnaireForm").serialize();
     var data = {
                 action: 'myajax-submit',
                 s: str,
                 beforeSend: function(){ 
                    $( "#tab" ).empty();
                    $("#tab").append("<img id='busyImg' src='busy.gif'/>");
                    }
                }; 

        if(ValidateQuestions())
        {
        jQuery.post("thankyou.php?t=<?php echo $sid;?>", data,  function(response) { 
        //alert('Got this from the server: ' + response);
        $( "#tab" ).empty().append( response );
        } );
        }
        else { alert("Answer all questions"); }
     return false;   
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: post hmtl too. Does all radio buttons have same `name` ?

Comment: @Ani Yeah all the Radio Buttons have same name..

Comment: @Ani as I mentioned in the question detail that its working fine on chrome and firefox. only have this issue in IE

Comment: post html. If you have same name for radio button for all question's, your html is wrong.

Comment: I mean to say I have 2 groups of radio buttons in my questionnaire

Comment: first group has name question1

second radio group has name question2

so on upto question20

Comment: your `checkRadio` function is wrong. Unless you post hmtl it's hard to explain.

Comment: Form Code is causing issues while I post it here. thats why I am explaining that the naming convention is right because I mentioned earlier that

ITS WORKING FINE ON OTHER BROWSERS AND POSTING ANSWER SUCCESSFULLY

Comment: Create a fiddle link, fiddle.net

Comment: @Ani I think you haven;t read my code properly name in checkradio function is parameter and I am passing the name of every radio button from ValidateQuestion() function

Comment: I did read your code. The reason I am saying this is because you are trying to check if each radio button is checked instead of each radio button with unique name is checked.

Comment: @Ani here is the link you can check here  http://jsfiddle.net/arslankhd/eNt3c/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/eNt3c/4/

```
function checkRadio(name)
{
       if($("input[name='"+ name + "']").is(':checked'))
       { return true; }
        alert("Please select " + name);
        return false;
}
```

Comment: I have to check on all browsers that would take 2 to 3 minutes so wait for some time

Comment: I checked this on chrome.. now I selected all the options and alert message is repeating at chrome

Comment: Yeah now its working fine can tell me what was wrong with my code.

Comment: I was using this function
`function checkRadio(name)
 {
   var radio = document.forms.myForm[name];
   for (var option in radio)
   {
  if(radio[option].checked)
  { return true; }
   }
   return false;
 }`

Comment: can you tell me how I can change this method to show which answer was not selected by the user.. I mean if someone missed 17th question than I want to show message like "Answer 17th question"

Comment: The problem with your solution was it was trying to check if all radio buttons of each questions were selected(by all I mean all radio buttons /question)

Comment: how I can change this method to show which answer was not selected by the user.. I mean if someone missed 17th question than I want to show message like "Answer 17th question"

Comment: You can add an alert - `alert("Please select " + name);` check updated answer

Comment: Thank you for your heli Ani.. Can you tell me one thing more

visit this link http://centangle.com/demo/surveyfront/questions/reports.php

in this link I am showing the charts.. In the Pie Chart on some areas its not displaying the value. I mean whom percentage is less than 5.. than that percentage is not written of that part of pie

Comment: Svg is not created properly. It's not showing the `text` tag inside the `<g>` tag